# Can this expression be represented by a Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams

As a preliminary example, the so-called $H$-diagram in position space defined by

$$H_{13,24} := \int \frac{dx_5 d x_6}{(2\pi)^{10}} \frac{1}{x_{15}^2 x_{35}^2 x_{26}^2 x_{46}^2 x_{56}^2} \tag{1}$$

can be Fourier-transformed into momentum space, and it gives:

$$\tilde{H}_{13,24} = -(2\pi)^8 \frac{1}{p_1^2 p_2^2 p_3^2 p_4^2 (p_1 + p_3)^2} \delta(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4), \tag{2}$$

which can be represented as a Feynman diagram and corresponds to the "slashed-box" integral:

[image]

I *know* that this is the case (from literature), but honestly I do not really see a way to derive it smoothly from eq.$(2)$ if I didn't know the result.

I have another similar integral in position space, which I transformed into momentum space. After some manipulations, the most complicated of its terms has the following form:

$$\frac{1}{p_1^2 p_2^2 p_3^4 p_4^4 (p_1+p_3)^2} \delta(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4) \tag{3}$$

This is a $4$-loop integral I believe, and I was wondering if this could be represented by a Feynman diagram in the same way as eq. $(2)$ turned out to be the slashed-box diagram?

Comment: How does (2) relate to the figure?

Comment: @Oбжорoв As mentioned below the picture, I know that $(2)$ relates to this diagram from the literature, but I do know how to relate them. It might be that we have to define things such that $p_1+p_3=k_1+k_3-l_1$ but I am not sure.